# UITableView: Change selected cell background color

Tags: objective-c, tvos

I am not able to change the white background when navigating in a `UITableView` on tvOS.

I edited the background / text color on the whole table for design purposes so the white selected background is annoying.

I tried:

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

But it doesn't update the highlighted background color.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tvOS use focus to show the current selected item. To change the backgroundColor, override the didUpdateFocusInContext() method in your cell class.

```
public override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    context.previouslyFocusedView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    context.nextFocusedView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

Comment: thanks , I m only objective C not swift and don't have a cell class. if there is no other solution, I will subclass UITableViewCell and override this method.

Comment: working fine with objective C with custom UITableViewCell , thanks !

Comment: Thanks, bizarrely though, that actually stops the selection zoom and other effects?

Comment: Ah!  you have to call super.didUpdateFocusInContext to maintain the behavior.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply disable this by using the focusStyle:

```
self.focusStyle = UITableViewCellFocusStyle.Custom
```

This will disable the white background, but will also disable any default zoom animation. You should handle this by yourself using the custom `UITableViewCellFocusStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a UIView and set that as your backgroundview in your CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CategoryCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 405, 60)];

    bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
```